# How to correctly deserialize ItemStack?

Tags: java, gson, bukkit

I'm working on a way to save ItemStacks in a MySQL-Database. The serializing and saving works fine but if I deserialize it, I just get the Item without the ItemMeta (e.g. Item isn't enchanted after deserializing).

Has anyone an idea how to deserialize it correctly? I found much about this on the internet but everything was outdatet and hasn't worked with 1.16.4.

**My functions:**

```
private static String itemStackToString(ItemStack item) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.toJson(item.serialize());
}

private static ItemStack stringToItemStack(String str) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Map<String, Object> map = gson.fromJson(str, new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>(){}.getType());
    return ItemStack.deserialize(map);
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way to do this? I'm trying to do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is most likely that `ItemStack.deserialize` expects `"meta"` [to be an instance of `ItemMeta`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/stash/projects/SPIGOT/repos/bukkit/browse/src/main/java/org/bukkit/inventory/ItemStack.java?at=ffd8b28939b4ec84855f8a10c93463ec113def13#526). However because you are telling Gson to deserialize the data as `Map<String, Object>`, it does not know about this requirement and deserializes the `"meta"` property value as `Map` instead.

You could possibly work around this by writing a custom Gson `TypeAdapter` which handles this, but it might be still rather brittle.

Maybe you can in some way use `ConfigurationSection` for serialization as shown [here](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/how-do-i-get-save-an-itemstack-from-to-my-config.362120/#post-3328511), but I don't know how well that works or if it is the proper (and safe) solution to this.

Comment: Alright, I'll try it with `TypeAdapter`. Thank you for your answer.